# Installing Mapserver on a remote server

Tags: linux, server, mapserver

I'm quite new to UMN Mapserver and started learning and so far I've only being experimenting on my localhost. Maybe I'm overthinking about it but what if I wanted my application let's say to be on the internet "alive." I believe this does not necessarily mean that I have to set up a server at my home... right? So could I install Mapserver on a server I'm renting let's say ? Sorry if it's irrelevant question but just trying to understand the underlying logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, install it anywhere you want. You just have to install the data on that server also.